# Possible verbs to describe an actual ownwership of position, rather than less direct employment

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs

What are the possible verbs to describe a relationship between a company and a position (job), when I want to stress the fact that the company is the real, actual party which requires the work to be done, rather than a third part middleman which supplies workers as a commodity?

For example in the sentence:

> I would like all my personal data to be deleted from every data
>   storage  maintained by the company that **XXXXX**s the position for which
>   I applied.

Comment: by the company that will employ the person hired.

Comment: @aparente001 In this age of ubiquitous indirect employment, this could also mean a company that serves as a middleman.

Comment: I would like all my personal data to be deleted by the company that will employ the person hired from all their databases and servers.  I would like all my personal data deleted from databases and servers by the hiring company and all its middlemen, subsidiaries, and partner companies.  You could also ask at law.se.